# how to query for list of databases which are never backed up, and save that result into new table..?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

I want to find list of databases which are never backed up, I have code to list last backup time for all databases:

```
SELECT  
      sdb.Name AS DatabaseName
    , COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MAX(bus.backup_finish_date), 101), '-') AS LastBackUpTime
FROM sys.sysdatabases sdb
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bus ON bus.database_name = sdb.Name
GROUP BY sdb.Name
```

Comment: Put this at the end of your query: `having MAX(bus.backup_finish_date) is null`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.DbNeverBackUp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.DbNeverBackUp

SELECT [db_name] = sdb.name 
INTO dbo.DbNeverBackUp
FROM sys.sysdatabases sdb
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bus ON bus.database_name = sdb.name
WHERE bus.backup_finish_date IS NULL

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.DbNeverBackUp
```